# gstreamer webrtcbin with multiple sinkpads

Tags: javascript, webrtc, gstreamer

Hello im trying to develop an gstreamer webrtc SFU.

My question is if its possible to have an webrtcbin with multiple sinkpads?

I want to have for example webrtcbin1 connected to the gstreamer from the browser and it have one stream to the gstreamer server (video only) sending the webcam media and the gstreamer sending a videotestsrc.

But then when i do the same connection with a webrtcbin2 with the browser 2 and webrtcbin2 fires the signal pad-added i want to add this webrctbin2_srcpad to a new sinkpad of the webrtcbin1 and renegotiates the connection to get to streams in the browser 1.

So browser 1 would being getting the media from the browser2 and the videotestsrc in the same peer, with peerConnection.getRemoteStreams()[0] and [1] in the browser and using one single webrtcbin in the gst app.

Is this possible? and how to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would like to know if you figured out a way of doing this? as far as I know, renegotiation is not supported in gstreamer webrtcbin